# visual studio 2013 prerequisites fatal error during installation

Tags: visual-studio-2013, installation

I can't seem to install visual studio professional 2013

my machin info:

-windows 8.1

-i7

-8GB Ram

-enuough space to install.

Is there any fix? help please.

log :
[0170:23A0][2016-03-30T09:39:14]i319: Applied execute package: Msi_BuildTools_MSBuild_Res_amd64, result: 0x0, restart: None
[043C:0864][2016-03-30T09:39:14]i325: Registering dependency: {40b949d3-887f-4033-a194-615b15cd790e} on package provider: Microsoft.BuildTools.MSBuild_LP_amd64_kor,v12, package: Msi_BuildTools_MSBuild_Res_amd64
[043C:0864][2016-03-30T09:39:14]i301: Applying execute package: vsbsln_neu_28, action: Install, path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache{0B6BDD27-3097-4FE1-BDE6-1D5EC7399563}v12.0.21005\packages\64bitPrereq\x64\VS_Prerequisites_x64_neutral.msi, arguments: ' ARPSYSTEMCOMPONENT="1" MSIFASTINSTALL="7" VSEXTUI="1"'
[0170:23A0][2016-03-30T09:39:16]i000: MUX:  ExecuteError: Package (vsbsln_neu_28) failed: Error Message Id: 25541 ErrorMessage: Error 25541.Failed to open XML file C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\CONFIG\machine.config, system error: -2147024786
[043C:0864][2016-03-30T09:39:17]e000: Error 0x80070643: Failed to install MSI package.
[043C:0864][2016-03-30T09:39:17]e000: Error 0x80070643: Failed to execute MSI package.
[0170:23A0][2016-03-30T09:39:17]e000: Error 0x80070643: Failed to configure per-machine MSI package.
[0170:23A0][2016-03-30T09:39:17]i000: MUX:  Installation size in bytes for package: vsbsln_neu_28 MaxAppDrive: 0  MaxSysDrive: 2519040  AppDrive: 0  SysDrive: 643072
[0170:23A0][2016-03-30T09:39:17]i000: MUX:  Return Code:0x80070643 Msi Messages:25541 Result Detail:0 Restart:None
[0170:23A0][2016-03-30T09:39:17]i000: MUX:  Set Result: Return Code=-2147023293 (0x80070643), Error Message=25541, Result Detail=, Vital=True, Package Action=Install, Package Id=vsbsln_neu_28
[0170:23A0][2016-03-30T09:39:17]i319: Applied execute package: vsbsln_neu_28, result: 0x80070643, restart: None
[0170:23A0][2016-03-30T09:39:17]e000: Error 0x80070643: Failed to execute MSI package.
[043C:0864][2016-03-30T09:39:17]i318: Skipped rollback of package: vsbsln_neu_28, action: Uninstall, already: Absent
[0170:23A0][2016-03-30T09:39:17]i000: MUX:  Installation size in bytes for package: vsbsln_neu_28 MaxAppDrive: 0  MaxSysDrive: 0  AppDrive: 0  SysDrive: 0
[0170:23A0][2016-03-30T09:39:17]i000: MUX:  Return Code:0x0 Msi Messages:25541 Result Detail:0 Restart:None
[0170:23A0][2016-03-30T09:39:17]i000: MUX:  Reset execution Result
[0170:23A0][2016-03-30T09:39:17]i000: MUX:  Reset Result
[0170:23A0][2016-03-30T09:39:17]i319: Applied rollback package: vsbsln_neu_28, result: 0x0, restart: None
[043C:0864][2016-03-30T09:39:17]i351: Removing cached package: vsbsln_neu_28, from path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache{0B6BDD27-3097-4FE1-BDE6-1D5EC7399563}v12.0.21005\
[0170:23A0][2016-03-30T09:39:17]i000: MUX:  Apply Complete: Disk Space Used in bytes for Installation:  MaxAppDrive: 0  MaxSysDrive: 1391071232  AppDrive: 0  SysDrive: 1385730048
[0170:23A0][2016-03-30T09:39:17]i000: MUX:  Free Disk Space after install:  SystemDrive C:\ 73903370240 bytes  AppDrive C:\ 73903370240 bytes
[0170:23A0][2016-03-30T09:39:17]i000: MUX:  Go to Finished page.
[0170:23A0][2016-03-30T09:39:17]i399: Apply complete, result: 0x80070643, restart: None, ba requested restart:  No